# A simple toggle function

Tags: solidity

I am busy teaching myself how to write smart contracts in solidity.

pragma solidity 0.4.13;

I am writing a simple toggle state method and this is how I would do it in PHP:

```
function toggleActiveState() 
    public
    isCreator()
    returns (bool)
    {
        active = !active;
        logMessage('State has been updated', 0);
        return true;
    }
```

The above, however,  does not seem to work.

Would it be better to write it as:

```
function toggleActiveState() 
    public
    isCreator()
    returns (bool)
    {
        if (active)
        {
           active = false;
        } else {
           active = true;
        }
        logMessage('State has been updated', 0);
        return true;
    }
```

thanks!

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I've tried your code in remix.ethereum.org and it does work.

Comment: Strange, I probably was not testing it properly. I am using mist wallet and when I try to use the toggle method I am not seeing the state change....

Comment: If `toggleActiveState()` fails when called another option is that `isCreator()` is failing.